# The direction that gets me closest to a given point in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

Let $p \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $p=\lambda_1 e_1+...+\lambda_n e_n$ where $e_i$ are standard basis vectors then if I want to find the component along which I can get closest to the point $p$ then it will just be $e_j$ with $j \in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $\lambda_j$ satisfies $|\lambda_j| = max_{1 \leq i\ \leq n} \{|\lambda_1|,...,|\lambda_n|\}$ and the closest point to $p$ along this direction is $ \lambda_j e_j$. As $\lambda_j$ was maximum, we have
\begin{equation*}|\lambda_j| \geq \frac{|p|}{\sqrt{n}} \end{equation*} and
\begin{equation} |\lambda_j e_j - p | \leq \sqrt{\frac {n-1} {n} } |p|. \end{equation}

I am looking for similar estimates when $p$ is represented by a different basis. What can I say if the point $p= \alpha_1 x_1 +...+\alpha_n x_n$ where $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ are such that $ \angle(x_i, \text{span}(x_1,...,x_{i-1})) \geq \theta$ for $i=2,...,n$ and $\theta >0$. Can I choose a direction $x_j$, $j \in \{1,...,n\}$ so that $|\alpha x_j - p| \leq C |p|$ where $\alpha>0$, $C<1$ and may depend on $n$ and $\theta$?

This is a repost from stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041205/the-direction-that-gets-me-closest-to-a-given-point-in-mathbbrn) where I got no answers. Hopefully it's OK to repeat the question here.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. How can I show that for such $i$, $|\frac{p \cdot x_{i}}{x_i \cdot x_i }x_i - p| \leq C |p|$ with $C \in (0,1)$ though? Sorry if this is very obvious, I am not too sure what you meant by standard regression stuff - I'd appreciat some references that might help with this.

Comment: As $x\cdot x=|x|^2$ you get $p\cdot p-\frac{(p\cdot x)^2}{x\cdot x}\le C^2 p\cdot p$, so $C\ge 1-\frac{(p\cdot x)^2}{(x\cdot x)(p\cdot p)}$. You want $x$ to be the $x_i$ that maximizes $\frac{(p\cdot x_i)^2}{(x_i\cdot x_i)(p\cdot p)}$, or equivalently $\frac{p\cdot x_i}{|x_i|}$. (What I stated earlier about maximizing $\frac{p\cdot x_i}{x_i\cdot x_i}$ was wrong.)

Comment: Right. Was wondering if my condition on vectors being $\theta$ apart could help with this because you said it is equivalent to $det X \neq 0$ but It's a stronger statement than just linear independence.

Comment: Erranda: where I wrote $C\ge \dots$ should be $C^2\ge \dots$ of course. I seem to forget squares and square roots a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is quite obvious for n=2 and not so for higher dimensions. Would be awesome if someone else has any ideas on this. In any case, thanks very much for your input.

Comment: That's a nice observation - I will see if I can generalise it.

Comment: I deleted several comments that are superceded by my answer below.

Comment: The question is not trivial. It may follow from well known results, but I don't see a trivial proof, despite having worked many year with vcv matrices, linear regressions, t-values and all that. I think the decision to close was at the least a rushed one.

Comment: I would add that **if** the question deserved to be closed, it would be common courtesy on this site to give some reason and pointer in the right direction when closing (unless are dealing with an outrageously inappropriate question - definitely not the case here!).

Comment: @YaakovBaruch I agree. Perhaps the votes to close were influenced by the fact that the question was asked on MSE, but I think that as long as a note is left on the MSE question pointing to this one, then there is no risk of duplicated effort.

Comment: @YemonChoi I have added a link to this question on MSE post if that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p, x_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$, with $1\le i\le n$, define
$$\theta_i=\angle(x_i,\text{span}(\{x_j \;|\; j\ne i\})),\quad \theta=\min(\{\theta_i\})$$

$$\beta_i=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle(p,x_i),\quad\beta=\max(\{\beta_i\})$$

**CLAIM.**
$$\sin(\beta)\ge\frac{sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{n(1+(n-1)\cos(\theta))}}$$

**PROOF.**
Trivial if $\theta=0$, so assume $\theta>0$. Write $p$ and the $x_i$'s as $1\times n$ matrices and rescale them so that $pp^T=x_i x_i^T=1$. Let $X$ be the matrix with rows $x_1,\dots x_n$. Then $\theta>0$ implies that $X$ is invertible, therefore

$$(pX^T)(XX^T)^{-1}(pX^T)^T=pp^T=1$$

But $pX^T=(\sin(\beta_1),\dots \sin(\beta_n))$ and the inverse correlation matrix $(XX^T)^{-1}=(c_{ij})$ satisfies

$$\displaystyle c_{ij}=\frac{1}{\sin(\theta_i)\sin(\theta_j)}\cdot \frac{x'_i {x'_j}^T}{|x'_i||x'_j|}$$

where $x'_i$ is the component of $x_i$ orthogonal to $\text{span}(\{x_j \;|\; j\ne i\})$. (Different proofs can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140080/why-does-inversion-of-a-covariance-matrix-yield-partial-correlations-between-ran) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73463/what-does-the-inverse-of-covariance-matrix-say-about-data-intuitively), but a standard linear algebra text reference would be welcome.) Moreover $x'_j \perp x_i$ for $j\ne i$ also implies $\text{span}(\{x'_j \;|\; j\ne i\}$ is the hyperplane orthogonal to $x_i$, and thus $\angle(x'_i,\text{span}(\{x'_j\;|\; j\ne i\}))=\angle(\text{span}(\{x_j \;|\; j\ne i\}),x_i)=\theta_i$ and then $\angle(x'_i,x'_j)\ge \max(\theta_i,\theta_j)\ge \theta$. In conclusion

$$\displaystyle |c_{ij}|\le \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)^2}\quad\text{if } i\ne j$$
$$\displaystyle |c_{ii}|\le \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)^2}$$

and therefore
$$1=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}\sin(\beta_i)\sin(\beta_j)\le \sin(\beta)^2\sum_{i,j}|c_{ij}|\le \sin(\beta)^2\frac{n+(n^2-n)\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)^2}$$
$$\sin(\beta)\ge\frac{sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{n(1+(n-1)\cos(\theta))}}$$

This also implies the good (as $\theta\rightarrow 0$) first order approximation $\sin(\beta)\ge \sin(\theta)/n$. $\quad\blacksquare$

I verified empirically that $\frac{sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{n(1+(n-1)\cos(\theta))}}\ge \sin(\frac{\theta}{n})$, which would imply $\beta\ge\frac{\theta}{n}$ too, but I'll leave the proof of that as an exercise, if true.

The example in my other answer led me to **conjecture** that the best possible result should be
$$\sin(\beta)\ge \sin(\theta)\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)\tan(\theta)^2+n}{n((n-1)\tan(\theta)^2+n^2)}}$$

which is not much stonger than the claim, but probably much harder to prove.

Comment: Notice that it's also true that $c_{ij}=-\frac{1}{\sin(\theta_i)\sin(\theta_j)}\cdot \frac{x^{''}_{ij} {x^{''}_{ji}}^T}{|x^{''}_{ij}||x^{''}_{ji}|}$ where $x^{''}_{ij}$ is the component of $x_i$ orthogonal to $\text{span}(\{x_k \;|\; k\ne i,j\})$. The argument is unaffected by which approach is used, but I find the first one both simpler and more elegant, in that it shows the inverse correlation matrix itself as a variance-covariance matrix. The second formula seems to be the one more commonly mentioned, at least in statistics fori.

Comment: Just realized that the plural of forum is fora, not fori.

Comment: I believe that $\frac{sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{n(1+(n-1)\cos(\theta))}}$ is best possible after all, while the other conjectured formula was based on a calculation mistake. I'll check this and edit accordingly in a week or two, hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pair of long comments, not an answer. Hopefully it can help towards a full answer.

- First, I intend to show that the separation condition on the $x_i$ vectors formulated in the question may not be the right one.
- Second, I will produce what I think may be be the worst scenario under a stronger separation assumption, and consequently conjecture the specific formula that one may want to try to prove.

---

The question assumes $\forall i:\angle(x_i,\text{span}(x_1,...,x_{i-1})) \ge \theta$. This does *not* imply that $\forall i:\angle(x_i,\text{span}(\{x_j\;|\;j\ne i\})) \ge \theta$.
To see that, for a small $\theta>0$ consider the $\mathbb{R}^3$ vectors

$x_1=(\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta),0)$

$x_2=(0,1,0)$

$x_3=(-\cos(\theta),0,\sin(\theta))$

Then it's easy to check that

- $\angle(x_1,x_2)=\theta$
- $\text{span}(x_1,x_2)=xy$-plane
- $\angle(x_3,\text{span}(x_1,x_2))=\theta$
- $\text{span}(x_2,x_3)=xy$-plane tilted by $\theta$ around the $y$-axis
- $x'_1:=$ component of $x_1$ orthogonal to $\text{span}(x_2,x_3)$ $=x_1-\cos(\theta)x_2+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)x_3= (\sin(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)^2,0,\sin(\theta)^2\cos(\theta))$
- since $|x_1|=1$, $\sin(\angle(x_1,\text{span}(x_2,x_3)))^2=x'_1\cdot x_1=\sin(\theta)^4$
- hence $\angle(x_1,\text{span}(x_2,x_3))=O(\theta^2)$ as $\theta$ approaches $0$.
- finally, taking $p$ to be a vector orthogonal to the $(x_2,x_3)$-plane, the closest $x_i$ to $p$ is $x_1$ and the angle of separation is then $\pi/2-O(\theta^2)$.

I suspect the OP had in mind a stronger result (in $\theta$), which is not possible with the weak separation condition assumed.

---

The following example in $\mathbb{R}^n$ assumes the strong separation condition; in that case I conjecture that it is the worst possible scenario, which would imply that the smallest $\angle(x_i, p)$ is $\le \pi/2-\theta/n$.

Fix $0 \le h \le 1$ and define

$p=(1,1,\dots 1)$

$x_i=ne_i-p+h p$

Notice that $\text{span} (\{x_i\})$ is the hyperplane orthogonal to $p$ for $h=0$, and that for $h=1$ the $x_i$'s are maximally separated, that is orthogonal. So assume $0 < h\le 1$.

If $\alpha$ is the angle between $p$ and any of the $x_i$'s, then

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)=\frac{x_i\cdot p}{\sqrt{(p\cdot p)(x_i\cdot x_i)}}=\frac{h n}{\sqrt{n\big(n^2+n(1-h)^2-2n(1-h)\big)}}=\frac{h}{\sqrt{n-1+h^2}}$$

The angle $\theta$ between $x_i$ and $\text{span}(\{x_j \;\vert\; j\ne i\})$ is, for symmetry reasons, the same as the angle between $x_i$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{j\ne i} -x_j=x_i-nh p$:
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{-n^2h^2+n(n-1+h^2)}{\sqrt{n(n-1+h^2)\big(n^3h^2-2n^2h^2+n(n-1+h^2)\big)}}=\frac{(1-h^2)\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n-1+h^2)(h^2 n-h^2+1)}}$$

and therefore

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{h n}{\sqrt{(n-1+h^2)(h^2 n-h^2+1)}}$$

In conclusion

$$\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac{\sqrt{1+h^2 n-h^2}}{n}\ge\frac{1}{n}$$

which implies the wanted result:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\ge \frac{\theta}{n}$$

(it follows from $\sin(x)/x$ being monotonic and decreasing in $[0,\pi/2]$).

Comment: if the approximation $\frac{\sqrt{1+h^2 n-h^2}}{n}\ge\frac{1}{n}$ seems too rough for large $\theta$'s, one can express $h^2$ in terms of $n$ and $\tan(\theta)$, and end up with the exact formula $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=\sin(\theta)\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)\tan(\theta)^2+n}{n((n-1)\tan(\theta)^2+n^2)}}$.

Comment: In the light of your counter-example, I should re-consider my separation condition indeed.  Many thanks for this. I had not realised that my condition is weaker so that the angle with the span of the other (n-1) vectors may not necessarily be greater than $\theta$.

Comment: **ERRATA.** The last implication is wrong... monotonicity is true but what follows is the converse of what I stated: $\alpha\ge \beta/n\implies \sin(\alpha)\ge \sin(\beta)/n$